# Get date before current date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a datepicker that loads with the current date. However, I am trying to figure out how I can determine if the date selected by the user is BEFORE the current date and display a message. How might I be able to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
function LoadSelectedEvents()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: fullURL,
        dataType: 'xml',
        beforeSend:
            function () {
                ShowLoading();

            },
        success:
            function (xml) {
                HideLoading();

                //bring jquerypaging in
                $.getScript("../js/jqueryPaging.js");

                //initialize our datepicker
                $("#datepickercalendar").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'DD, MM dd, yy',
                    minDate: 0,
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        var dateAsString = dateText;
                        var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                        $(".easyPaginateNav").empty();
                        //ajax call on user select
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: fullURL,
                            dataType: 'xml',
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                ShowLoading();
                                $("#EventListHeaderDate").empty();
                                $("#feedContainer").empty();
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                HideLoading();
                            },
                            success: function (xml) {



                                //clear results
                                $("#feedContainer").empty();
                                var index = 0;

                                $("#EventListHeaderDate").text(dateAsString);

                                //find each ITEM and display
                                $(xml).find("item").slice(0, maxItems).each(function () {

                                    //find matches based on date
                                    var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                                    var itemDate = $(this).find("date").text();
                                    var itemTime = $(this).find("time").text();
                                    //alert(index);

                                    if (dateText == itemDate) {

                                        $("#feedContainer").fadeIn();
                                        $("#feedContainer").append("<div id='event'>" + "<span id='event-title'>" + title + "</span><br>" +
                                                    "<span id='event-date'>" + itemDate + "</span><br>" + "<hr></div>" + "");


                                        index++;
                                    }
                                });

                                if (index == 0) {
                                    $("#feedContainer").empty();
                                    $("#feedContainer").append("No Events for this Date.");
                                }


                                $("#feedContainer").easyPaginate({
                                    paginateElement: 'div#event',
                                    elementsPerPage: 2,
                                    effect: 'climb'
                                });

                                HideLoading();

                            }


                        });

                    }
                    //altField: "#EventListHeaderDate"
                }); //end datepicker initialization

                var index = 0;

                //our current date of datepicker in a variable
                var currentDate = $("#datepickercalendar").datepicker().val();
                $('#EventListHeaderDate').text(currentDate); //update header to reflect current (todays) date

                //parse XML
                $(xml).find("item").slice(0, maxItems).each(function () {


                    //find matches based on date
                    var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                    var itemDate = $(this).find("date").text();
                    var itemTime = $(this).find("time").text();



                    if (currentDate == itemDate) {
                        index++;
                        //alert(index);
                        $("#feedContainer").fadeIn();
                        $("#feedContainer").append("<div id='event'>" + "<span id='event-title'>" + title + "</span><br>" +
                                                    "<span id='event-date'>" + itemDate + "</span><br>" + "</div>" + "<hr>");
                    }
                });

                if (index == 0) {
                    $("#feedContainer").empty();
                    $("#feedContainer").append("No Events for this Date.");
                }

                //and paginate the results
                $("#feedContainer").easyPaginate({
                    paginateElement: 'div#event',
                    elementsPerPage: 2,
                    effect: 'climb'
                });

            },
        error: function () { $("#loading").replaceWith("Error: Could not fetch events"); }

    });       //end first ajax

}
```

Comment: Show your html and javascript code

Comment: I am using mindate in mine, but would still like to know how to accomplish this when turned off.

Comment: get the input value where user selected the data and make a function where it will verify it data is last then  the corrent data

Answer (score 0):

well you should user mindate but as you said you don't want so  do  this
html code

```
<input id='datapicker' value="06/15/2016">
```

java script code

```
<script>

function data_checker(){
    var input_data= $("#datapicker").val();
    if(Date.parse(input_data)-Date.parse(new Date()) < 0){
        alert("data too old");
    }

}
data_checker();
</script>
```

Comment: call the event onchange on the input you can see it working here https://jsfiddle.net/aa7kq637/